# What 'model' am I getting in my ListView delegate?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a QML [`ListView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) that I'm data-driving the delegates via a JavaScript array:

```
ListView {
    id:mylist
    model: [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] // JS objects
    delegate: MyRow { mydata: mylist.model[index] }
}
```

The above code works correctly. The code I originally wrote did not work as expected, however:

```
ListView {
    model: [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] // JS objects
    delegate: MyRow { mydata: model[index] }
}
```

`MyRow.qml` is just a Rectangle with a custom property and some laid-out children:

```
Rectangle {
    property var mydata
    color:'#eeeeff'; height:20
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill:parent
        Text { ... }
        Text { ... }
    }
}
```

When I ask for `model` inside `MyRow` delegate, what am I getting? It's not an array that can be accessed by `index`, nor is it an object with the properties that I want.

---

**Edit**: If I assign `model+""` to a string property in my delegate, I get `QQmlDMListAccessorData(0x13aee00)`.

Comment: As shown in the attachment on [this bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49983), a better workaround is to just use `modelData` instead of `mylist.model[index]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Models and Views in Qt Quick](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html#models):

> If there is a naming clash between the model's properties and the delegate's properties, the roles can be accessed with the qualified *model* name instead. For example, if a Text type had *type* or *age* properties, the text in the above example would display those property values instead of the *type* and *age* values from the model item. In this case, the properties could have been referenced as `model.type` and `model.age` instead to ensure the delegate displays the property values from the model item.

So, `model` is an accessor for named model roles. When you don't have any named roles, for example if the model is a number or a JS array, Qt cannot invent a name; instead you are provided the data via `modelData`. In other words, `model` is not useful when your model doesn't have named roles.

Comment: That documentation implies that `ListView { model:[{x:'Hello'},{x:'World'}]; delegate:MyRow{ mydata:model.x }}` should work; but instead I get `Unable to assign [undefined] to QString` (with `property string mydata` in `MyRow`). It may be [the bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-49983) I mentioned above.

Comment: That is a JS array, not a model with named roles, so you have to use `modelData` instead.

Comment: Yes, it is a JS array. (It always has been, in the question.) I also see in the documentation that `modelData` is to be used when ~"the model does not have named roles". However, that does not explain what `model` is in this case.

Comment: I thought the question was what `model` is. It is an accessor for named model roles. When you don't have any named roles, for example, the model is a number or a JS array, Qt cannot invent a name but you are provided the data via `modelData`.

Comment: No, the question was/is: _"When I ask for model inside MyRow delegate, what am I getting?"_

Comment: You have already answered that in your edit. You get `QQmlDMListAccessorData` when you ask for `model` in an item delegate. We have further explained what it is. I don't know what else you are expecting to be answered.

Comment: You give me more credit for understanding the internals of Qt than I am due. ;) I greatly appreciate your help, but I do not feel that your answer yet solves my question. My question was not "How do I get access to the model data in this case?". I already had a workaround to `model` not working (and I appreciate that `modelData` is even cleaner than my workaround). My question was: "What the heck is this thing that `model` is returning?" Just seeing `QQmlDMListAccessorData` when I call `toString()` on it does not answer that for me. Is it useful? Is it useless?

Comment: The accessor for named model roles is not useful when your model doesn't have named roles.